# Duplicated lines in a dataframe, using multiple fields to check for duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to identify duplicates in a dataframe, based on four fields matching: 'dhid_y', 'from_y', 'to_y' and 'bound_y'. the code below, using .duplicated on the dataframe with 'subset' pointed at the four fields under consideration. The result should be that the duplicates are flagged as 'true' and the first occurrence should remain as 'false'. I'll use this info later in the script. However, not all of the duplicates are being spotted. Seems to work when just using dhid_y, but when I add additional fields, it seems to misbehave - although does run!

```
import pandas as pd

df_merged = pd.read_csv('merged_example_matched.csv')

conditions_2 = [(df_merged.duplicated(subset=['dhid_y', 'from_y', 'to_y', 'bound_y'], keep='first')) == True]
print(conditions_2)
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here in how I'm using this duplicated option?

[duplicated expected to be identified with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mDbq.jpg)

[rows code identifies as duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOBdp.jpg)

[highlighted entries which should have been identified as duplicates but were not by my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWxCz.jpg)

Comment: I didn't use the duplicated function so far - didn't even know it exists.
Usually, I do a `groupby` on the columns concerned with a `count()` aggregation.
The code would than look like `df_agg = df.groupby['dhid_y', 'from_y', 'to_y', 'bound_y'].count()` where `count >1` you have a duplicate.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's hard to say why you're seeing duplicates - maybe there are extra spaces that make rows "look" like duplicates?

Comment: thank you both, I've found that the fields I was looking at for duplicates were numeric fields with differences of something like 0.0000000001 due to some rounding issue. Applying a rounding to those numeric fields to 3.d.p solved it, so the code now works. Apologies for the lack of data I'm new to the scripting, so just posted screenshots. Thanks a lot for responding I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct, but needed to round to 3 d.p. before looking for duplicates in my numeric fields. There was a difference of something like 0.00000001 between my 'matching' fields, so were not being treated as duplicates.